# How can I map repeated key presses to specific?

Tags: keyboard, gnome-terminal, 19.04, vim

Can I map repeated key presses in Ubuntu to particular keys? For example pressing `aaa` would give me capital `A`, like I'm doing in my `Vim`. Because modifier keys are too far away for my fingers to reach and come back again for normal typing. And `Capslock` key isn't nice, because it makes me to toggle Capslock again to go back to normal. Repeated key presses seems way more faster than moving away finger go for modifier keys and come back again.

Any work-arounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either turn on [Sticky Keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-stickykeys.html.en) (included in Ubuntu) or take a look at [USB foot petals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008MU0TBU) ([more](https://www.delcomproducts.com/webpage.asp?id=32)) which explicitly support Linux and imitate the Shift key of your keyboard.

Comment: Aargh!...didnt know there is keyboard for your feet as well!

Comment: Well, not a keyboard per se, more like the dwell pedal on a piano.